# Php - Code comparing value of database to the value send by android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

Update :-

It save the data to table if same id doesn't exist in the table.

**Here's the response I get using this in my response**

Log.i("Response", "response: " + response);

```
Response: response: <br />
                                                                  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: id in <b>/storage/ssd2/319/3199319/public_html/leaderboard.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
                                                                  <br />
                                                                  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: connect in <b>/storage/ssd2/319/3199319/public_html/leaderboard.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
                                                                  <br />
                                                                  <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in <b>/storage/ssd2/319/3199319/public_html/leaderboard.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
                                                                  <br />
                                                                  <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>/storage/ssd2/319/3199319/public_html/leaderboard.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
                                                                  <br />
                                                                  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: time in <b>/storage/ssd2/319/3199319/public_html/leaderboard.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
                                                                  {"success":false}
```

---

I have created a php code to verify if the database has id already exist or not. If it exist then I compared the value of time with the value I sent to it else save the value to the table. 
If value send by me is less than that of value in database then update the table else, request is cancelled. But I am getting error. Please help.

My Php Code :-

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id3199319_s", "pass", "id3199319_k");
$name = $_POST["name"];
$time = $_POST["time"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

function registerUser() {
    global $connect, $name, $time, $id;
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO leaderboard (name, time, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sis", $name, $time, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
}

function nameAvailable() {
    global $connect, $id;
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE id = ?"); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 
    if ($count < 1){
        return true; 
    }else {           
        return false; 
    }
}

function updateTime(){
   $sql = "SELECT time from leaderboard WHERE id = $id;";
   $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, $sql));
   if($time < $res['time']){
        $sql = "UPDATE table leaderboard SET time = $time where id=$id";
        $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if(!$res){
            die("Query not executed " . mysqli_error($connect));
             $response["success"] = false;
            } else {
                    $response["success"] = true;
        }
    }
}

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

 if (nameAvailable()){
    registerUser();
    $response["success"] = true;  
      } else {
        updateTime();
      }

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**Volley Request**

```
public void winner_registration(){

    String tm = timer_box.getText().toString();
    String[] tmm = tm.split(":");

    int hr = Integer.parseInt(tmm[0]);
    int hr_sec = hr*60*60;
    int minn = Integer.parseInt(tmm[1]);
    int minn_sec = minn*60;
    int secc = Integer.parseInt(tmm[2]);

    int totalTime = hr_sec+minn_sec+secc;
    String myName = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getName();
    String id = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();

    Response.Listener<String> response = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success){
                    Toast.makeText(Play.this, "Details Submitted To LeaderBoard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(Play.this, "Something Went Wrong! Score not Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                Handler h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        score_submit_progressdialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(Play.this, Home.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }, 50);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(Play.this, "Something Went Wrong :"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    RegisterWinner registerRequest = new RegisterWinner(myName,totalTime,id, response );
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Play.this);
    queue.add(registerRequest);
}
```

**RegisterWinner**

public class RegisterWinner extends StringRequest {

```
public static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "URL";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterWinner(String name, int totalTime, String id, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener , null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("time", String.valueOf(totalTime));
    params.put("id", id);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

**Here's the Error I am getting when the table need to be updated**

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you get as response in `public void onResponse(String response)` ?

Comment: You get html back from php and you try to parse it as json. Log tbe result and you will see.

Comment: I get a JSON response only

Comment: response I get is shown in above image

Comment: Try this to show your String response

        `@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("Response", "response: " + response);
            ...
        }`

Comment: Yes. And that is not json isnt it!? See the <br> tag. It is html!

Comment: response is added in update

Comment: Yes. You see that it is no json. What are you asking?

Comment: your problem is in php code so try to check it via postman, try log your params `@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
log.d("message", params.toString());
}`

Comment: I dont know why I am getting this response.
What i want is if the time column in the database of a particular id is greater than what I am sending in my request, then my new data should be updated there, else cancel the request.

Comment: The response is telling you the coding errors in your php script. And on which line. Cant you read?

Comment: I understand that their is something wrong but I am not a php developer, thats the reason I am not able to correct the code. Can you help ?

Comment: You have never heard of an undefined variable? And you cannot count to 31?

Comment: Place a log statement in getParams() to see if it ever gets called. You were asked this before but you did not react.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I just changed the php code and it worked flawlessly.
Here's the updated code :-

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "db", "pass", "host");
$name = $_POST["name"];
$time = $_POST["time"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
function registerUser() {
global $connect, $name, $time, $id;
 $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO leaderboard (name, time, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sis", $name, $time, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
}
function nameAvailable() {
    global $connect, $id;
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE id = ?"); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 
    if ($count < 1){
        return true; 
    }else {           
        return false; 
    }
}
$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  
if (nameAvailable()){
    registerUser();
    $response["success"] = true;  
      } else {
        $sql = "SELECT time from leaderboard WHERE id = $id;";
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, $sql));
if($time < $res['time']){
        $sql = "UPDATE leaderboard SET time = $time where id=$id";
        $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if(!$res){
            die("Query not executed " . mysqli_error($connect));
             $response["success"] = false;
            } else {
                    $response["success"] = true;
        }
    }
      }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```